# GWT doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt

Today I try to compile my first GWT project (using Eclipse). It has default 'en' location and also 'bg' location. I'm using ui.xml files with corresponding properties files.

The only problem that I have is that project doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8. No problems with Firefox and Chrome. The start screen is ok, but when I upload file to my servlet and receive the response JSON something is happening and I get this JS error

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.5; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Tue, 27 Jul 2010 12:57:53 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 754
Char: 26
Code: 0
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8888/infonotarywebservices/AD560C7F0D3FD1787F6B5CDB74891CDC.cache.html
```

The row with error is:

```
function Ox(a,b){var c,d;c=eval(b.a);d=Gv(new Bv);d.d.innerHTML=FD;(fd(),d.d).innerText=KH;Mx(a,c,d);Uu(a.d);Zv(a.d.g,d);Pv(d,true,true)}
```

What I have to do know?

P.S. The error is happening no mater what localization version I open in IE

Comment: Have you tried compiling the source code with 'pretty' or 'detailed' output? That should give you a better idea of where the problem is.

Comment: What does your GWT module file look like? Have you added a restriction on which user agents to generate for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my native javascript source code, not the source compiled from GWT. In fact the problem was syntax error in JSON that is generated from my servlet.

I used to put comma after each array element, no mater is it last or not (like PHP arrays)

```
[
  {"a": "b"},
  {"a": "b"},
  {"a": "b"},
  {"a": "b"}, <- invalid comma separator
]
```

The Firefox and Chrome understand this, but eval in Internet Explorer is failing

Comment: I was under the impression that extra commas would make IE7 and earlier not accept this, but IE8 finally fixed this.  Is IE8 running in compatibility mode?